# Вычисление выражения с помощью рекурсии на c++

Tags: c++, рекурсия

[image: Выражение]

Я попытался написать свою функцию, но всё равно есть проблемы:

```
float findMain2(int n, int m = 1) {
    if (m == n) return sqrt(1 + n + n);
    else {
        return sqrt(1 + (n + m) * findMain2(n, ++m));
    }
}
```

Если кратко, то я не понимаю почему изменяются все значения m при увеличении.

Comment: при увеличении чего?

Comment: Замените `++m` на `m+1`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior

Comment: Так ведь тогда m будет передаваться как 2
upd понял, спасибо